# Determine what View is going to be rendered in @RenderBody()

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

In `_Layout.cshtml` is it possible to determine what View is going to be rendered in `@RenderBody()` ?

Comment: What exactly do you need? It not quite clear what you mean.

Comment: Do you want to render different views based on some conditions?

Comment: @AndreiV let's say that have /Home/MyView I want to get "MyView" inside of _Layout.cshtml

Comment: @ShaikhFarooque nope I actually want to include some .js dynamically based on the View.

Comment: Do you want to get a list of names for the view which are being rendered?

Comment: @gsharp: Why not add that .js directly on that view. Principally your layout page should not have any information about the views. You just give it a view and it will render it using <RenderBody> tag.

Comment: @Yogi yes I know I could do that. I was just wondering if there's a way to automate it. I have a lot of views and a custom script per view and didn't want to add a reference by code line in each view.

Comment: @gsharp: Adding line of code in each view will improve maintainability and separation. If you do what you want, how many line of code you will write and where? Think about clean and maintainable code first. I am not saying that your thinking is wrong at all.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can get the View (i.e. *Index.cshtml*) through `((RazorView)ViewContext.View).ViewPath`

Example for your needs:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/Scripts/@(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Server.MapPath(((RazorView)ViewContext.View).ViewPath))).js"></script>
```

If you need your actual View (i.e. *_Layout.cshtml*), you can use `VirtualPath` instead.

---

**Old answer**
Reading your comments, you want to add a

```
<script ...>...</script>
```

depending on the view but outside of `@RenderBody()`?

Then put

```
@RenderSection("Scripts", required:false)
```

and in your view define the section like

```
@section Scripts {
   <script ...>...</script>
}
```

So you don't need to maintain your _Layout.cshtml since every View defines their own scripts.

Here is an easy explanation: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor

Comment: I know that I can do that, but it's not what I want.... I'm just experimenting on how to include index.js into view index.cshtml (and detail.js into detail.cshtml and so on..) without any manual typing. my idea was to place a piece of code in _layout.cshtml that will do t he work for me... and for that i need to know the view..

Comment: I just edited my answer. So is this, what you want to achieve?

Comment: I read @Matt edited answer and think this is the simplest way.

Comment: Yes this is it @Matt. You are my Hero of the day :-)

Answer (score 1):

What you *can* do is check `Html.ViewContext.RouteData.Values`. That's a dictionary with controller, action, and id (as necessary).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I need to know the View and not the Action.

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/383145/RenderBody-RenderPage-and-RenderSection-methods-in) article and it will solve your problem.

**Edit**

RenderBody

> What is RenderBody?
>
> In layout pages, renders the portion of a content page that is not
>   within a named section. [MSDN]
>
> How RenderBody works (graphical presentation)?
>   [image]

Comment: RenderBody() does not have any overloaded method so obviously you can't   define the view that you want to render.

Answer (score 0):

The `@RenderBody()` renders the view controlled by the controller. so if your controller is like this.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index() // Renders File /Views/Home/Index.cshtml
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
```

Then the `public ActionResult Index()` **Index.cshtml** will be the view it will render located int the /Views/Home folder.

You can add to the **Index.cshtml** or **_Layout.cshtml** view to render other **Views** or **partialViews** By adding `@Html.Partial("_MyView")` as shown below.

```
        @Html.Partial("_LayoutHeaderHeader")
        @Html.Partial("_LayoutHeaderNavbar")
```

Sometimes it is easy to setup a few layout pages to call from different Views.

If you want to call scripts to you View you should always create a _PartialView and place your scripts in the partial view and call that View at the bottom of your View like this `@Html.Partial("_MyView")` and the scripts will set properly.

Here is a good tutorial. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/698246/ASP-NET-MVC-Special-Views-Partial-View-and-Layout

Comment: Hi Rich. That isn't going to work because you can do return View("AnotherViewThatDoesntMatchTheActionName")

Comment: I apologize, When i read the question i assumed you were looking for details to know what view is rendered by default.

Answer (score 0):

If you derive all your models from a base model then you could add a property to you base model that returns the controller name, which you can get using

`this.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();`

It would be even better if you had a `BaseController` class because you could put this in the constructor and never have to touch it again.

Since you would be returning a descendant of the base Model to your index page which has the controller name, now you could use some scheme base on `@Model.ControllerName`. If your controller services multiple views the property could be updated to indicate a certain view name.

I don't think you can get the name of a Partial inside the index unless you use jquery and by that point the page resources have already been loaded.

**Edit:** One other trick would be to create your own version of @Html.Partial() HtmlHelper class. So you have **@Html.MyPartial("ViewName")** and inside that method call the internal function that generates Html.Partial and then inject your dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: I just read your comments about the issue and think that the better way is using the code snipplet provided by @Matt in another answer.

You can use the **@section** razor statement inside your view to inform wich script should be loaded.

**Layout template placeholder**

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

**View Code**

```
@section scripts {
    <script src="~/Scripts/custom-imgedit.js"></script>
}
```

The example above inform that the custom-imgedit.js will be loaded in the render section placeholder. Note: You can even use bundles like @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/myCustomScripts")